# How bad is it to have two methods with the same name but different signatures in two classes?

Tags: design-patterns, software, class-design, design, class-diagram

I have a design problem related to a public interface, the names of methods, and the understanding of my API and code.

I have two classes like this:

```
class A:
    ...
    function collision(self):
        ....

...

class B:
    ....
    function _collision(self, another_object, l, r, t, b):
        ....
```

The first class has one public method named *collision*, and the second has one private method called _*collision*. The two methods differs in argument type and number.

As an example let's say that _*collision* checks if the object is colliding with another object with certain conditions *l*, *r*, *t*, *b* (collide on the left side, right side, etc) and returns *true* or *false*. The public *collision* method, on the other hand, resolves all the collisions of the object with other objects.

The two methods have the same name because I think it's better to avoid overloading the design with different names for methods that do almost the same thing, but in distinct contexts and classes.

Is this clear enough to the reader or I should change the method's name?

Comment: If the real method names are 'm' and '_m' then yes, you should change them. Otherwise, giving a sensible answer without the *real* names of the classes or methods is not really useful.

Comment: @RJLohan Thanks for the advice! I edit the question.

Comment: If you want to avoid confusion, why not just name them `Acollision` and `_Bcollision`, or something similar?

Comment: @BrianSnow I think is not really necessary because one of the methods is private.

Answer (score 22):

These functions both have to do with collisions, but *what* they do is very different, so giving them names that more clearly describe what they actually do will make it easier for future developers to understand the difference without having to look at the logic inside.

The method that checks if the object is colliding with another object could be called `checkForCollision`.

The method that resolves collisions of the object with other objects could be called `resolveCollisions` or `handleCollisions`.

When two functions do almost the same thing is often the *best time* to give them more specific names to make their difference clear.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say that there is nothing wrong with this.  Method overloading is a pretty standard practice, for multiple reasons.  If you have the same exact functionality, just for two different series of parameters, then using the same exact name makes perfect sense, and it also helps to clarify that the parameter list should be roughly the only real difference between the two functions.  It really does make it easier to code in languages that support it.

As for having those two functions do two slightly different things (A.collision() being more general than B._collision()), in this case, it is fine for two reasons:

1. They're not really overloaded.  "collision" <> "_collision" (unless Python's doing something here I'm unaware of).
2. They're not really overloaded.  class A <> class B.  Even if they did have the same basic name, other programmers should be able to distinguish between functions in two different classes fairly easily (unless one is subclassing other).  Different classes obviously tend to do things differently.

Answer (score 3):

**In layman's words:**

1. **Method names should be verbs**, so both names are inadequate.
2. When you give them appropiate names ( with a verb ), it's unlikely the two method's names will coincide.
3. Even if the two methods had the same name, **they are in different classes**, and there's no way of confusing them because of their having different namespaces.
4. **There's no style (or otherwise) rules** stating that two distinct classes or interfaces cannot have methods with the same name, even if they have the same signature (parameter list).

For example

```
// there's absolutely no problem with this totally unrelated (or related) classes:
databaseClient.connect();
odbcSource.connect();
navii.connect();
fireHose.connect();
```

**Short answer: there's nothing wrong with it.**

Comment: @Casey Typo fixed

Comment: If you're writing pure functions, (and there's increasingly more reason to do so) there's no functional difference between functions and values. Subsequently, there's increasingly less reason to force method names into verbs.